# Database Error when I attempt to Publish an Entry

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields, database-error

I created a new channel and a field group that has a large number of custom fields. When I attempt to Publish a new entry I get the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column ‘field_id_0’ in ‘field list’
>
> SELECT `field_id_0` FROM (`exp_channel_data`) WHERE `channel_id` = ‘0’
>
> Filename: fieldtypes/select/ft.select.php
>
> Line Number: 154

All other channels work fine and publish without error. I did a search and do not have a field_id_0, nor do I have a channel_id 0.

I enabled Template Debugging and do not get any errors there.

Is there a limit to the number of custom fields you can have with a field group/channel?

Any clues what may be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of EE are you using? and what add-ons are being used to establish the new channel?

Comment: Hi Lee, I just found the solution. See my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

Here's the deal. I had several 'Select Dropdown' fields and on one of those fields a radio button was not selected:

- Populate the menu manually
- Populate the menu from another channel field

If one of them is not selected it throws this error. Personally I think this is a bug, but at least there is a solution.